# I want to avoid Redirecting (301) with Scrapy and create a json file

Tags: python, json, scrapy

> **Thing I want to do**

I want to scrape Web with Scrapy and make json file.
I am currently studying at "Data Visualization with Python and JavaScript". Attempting to make a json file failed. I think that the cause is "Redirecting (301)", but I do not know how to handle it.

> **Directory structure**

```
nobel_winners    scrapy.cfg    data

/nobel_winners:
__init__.py    items.py    pipelines.py    spiders
__pycache__    middlewares.py    settings.py

/nobel_winners/spiders:
__init__.py        __pycache__        nwinners_list_spider.py
```

> **Work process/Code**

Enter the following code in nwinners_list_spider.py in / nobel_winners / spiders.

```
#encoding:utf-8

import scrapy, re
BASE_URL = 'http://en.wikipedia.org'

class NWinnerItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    year = scrapy.Field()
    category = scrapy.Field()
    country = scrapy.Field()
    gender = scrapy.Field()
    born_in = scrapy.Field()
    date_of_birth = scrapy.Field()
    date_of_death = scrapy.Field()
    place_of_birth = scrapy.Field()
    place_of_death = scrapy.Field()
    text = scrapy.Field()

class NWinnerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'nwinners_full'
    allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates_by_country"]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split('/')[-1]

        h2s = response.xpath('//h2')
        h2s = h2s[3:]

        for h2 in list(h2s)[:2]:
            country = h2.xpath('span[@class="mw-headline"]/text()').extract()
            if country:
                winners = h2.xpath('following-sibling::ol[1]')
                for w in winners.xpath('li'):
                    wdata = process_winner_li(w, country[0])
                    request = scrapy.Request(
                        wdata['link'],callback = self.parse_bio,dont_filter = True)
                    request.meta['item'] = NWinnerItem(**wdata)
                    yield request

    def parse_bio(self, response):

        item = response.meta['item']
        href = response.xpath("//li[@id='t-wikibase']/a/@href").extract()
        if href:
            request = scrapy.Request(href[0],callback = self.parse_wikidata,dont_filter = True)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse_wikidata(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        property_codes = [
            {'name':'date_of_birth','code':'P569'},
            {'name':'date_of_death','code':'P570'},
            {'name':'place_of_birth','code':'P19','link':True},
            {'name':'place_of_death','code':'P20','link':True},
            {'name':'gender','code':'P21','link':True}
        ]

        p_template = '//*[@id="{code}"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]{link_html}/text()'

        for prop in property_codes:

            link_html = ''
            if prop.get('link'):
                link_html = '/a'
            sel = response.xpath(p_template.format(code=prop['code'], link_html=link_html))
            if sel:
                item[prop['name']] = sel[0].extract()

        yield item

def process_winner_li(w, country=None):

    wdata = {}
    wdata['link'] = BASE_URL + w.xpath('a/@href').extract()[0]

    text = ''.join(w.xpath('descendant-or-self::text()').extract())

    wdata['name'] = text.split(',')[0].strip()

    year = re.findall('\d{4}', text)
    if year:
        wdata['year'] = int(year[0])
    else:
        wdata['year'] = 0
        print('no year in ', text)

    category = re.findall('Physics|Chemistry|Physiology or Medicine|Literature|Peace|Economics', text)
    if category:
        wdata['category'] = category[0]
    else:
        wdata['category'] = ''
        print('no category in ', text)

    if country:
        if text.find('*') != -1:
            wdata['country'] = ''
            wdata['born_in'] = country
        else:
            wdata['country'] = country
            wdata['born_in'] = ''

    wdata['text'] = text
    return wdata
```

Enter the following code in the root directory.

```
scrapy crawl nwinners_full -o data/nwinners_full.json
```

> **Error**

The following display appears and no data is entered in the json file.

```
2018-08-05 04:37:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates_by_country> (referer: None) ['cached']
2018-08-05 04:37:35 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Milstein> from <GET http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Milstein>
```

> **What I tried / thought**

1.I thought that the function was a problem, I confirmed the movement of each function. Each function itself operated without problems.

2.I tried to find out whether Redirecting (301) was the cause and tried to change settings.py. However, I did not know what kind of processing should be concrete.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this solves!
If redirecting is the issue you can use:

```
 yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse , meta={'dont_redirect': True})
```

This will prevent spider from redirecting.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

`request = scrapy.Request(href[0],callback = self.parse_wikidata,dont_filter = True, meta={'dont_redirect': True})`

As I put it in the above, nothing changed.

`request = scrapy.Request(
                        wdata['link'],callback = self.parse_bio,dont_filter = True, meta={'dont_redirect': True})`

When putting it as above, the display as below appears.

`INFO: Ignoring response <301 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Milstein>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed`

Comment: Also, when reviewing, there was a display as follows.

`[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityPage/Q155525>`

To be honest, I do not really know what is causing it ...